# Error Ignoring multiple install campaigns using GoogleAnalytics

Tags: android, google-analytics, google-analytics-firebase

I was testing Google Play campaign attribution for my app when I saw the following error log :

```
06-19 14:17:55.416  14424-14466/com.myapp.android E/GAv4﹕ Ignoring multiple install campaigns. original, new: utm_source=testSource, utm_source=testSource2
```

**testSource** and **testSource2** are utm_source's I generate using the following test broadcasting method :

```
adb shell am broadcast -a com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER -n com.myapp.android/com.google.android.gms.analytics.CampaignTrackingReceiver --es "referrer" "utm_source=testSource&utm_medium=testMedium&utm_term=testTerm&utm_content=testContent&utm_campaign=testCampaign"
```

I see hits for only **testSource** on the GoogleAnalytics website.

Can anyone explain what does the error mean ?
Why does **testSource2** does not show on the GoogleAnalytics website having come from a different source ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The error occurs since Google Play Services broadcast it for only once when the app is downloaded.

The docs say:

> When your app is downloaded from Google Play Store, the Play Store app broadcasts an INTENT_REFERRER to your app during installation. This intent contains the value of the referrer parameter of the link used to reach your app's Google Play Store page, if one was present.

I was testing it for another source on the same installed apk. 
To test for a new source:

```
1) Uninstall the apk 

2) Broadcast again.
```

You'll definitely see the hits for your new source on Google Analytics website after some time.

Comment: I have one more dought when user download app from link then how can get that intent of reffer paramiter

Comment: @Sara , can you please tell me , after how much time, campaign data is displayed on analytics's site ?